# Use indexing on outer join and group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm quite new to mysql optimizing and indexing but on my new project i will give it a try to use indexing more and get a better understanding.

But now i struggle with joins and group_concat and indexing i can't get it to work correctly
i have set index on tags.item_id and items.id have primary index.

What i can see from my EXPLAIN Query it's not using any INDEX for this query.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT i.id, i.title, i.content, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.name SEPARATOR ",") as tags 
FROM items as i 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags as t ON t.item_id = i.id 
WHERE i.id = 103 GROUP BY i.id
```

Result:

```
1   SIMPLE  i   const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   
1   SIMPLE  t   ref item_id item_id 5   const   4
```

Hope someone can help me out and explain what i'm doing wrong and how i should do to get a correct query thats using indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an index on a function in MySql. A solution would be storing the tags in another column of your table and index it. Also index t.item_id ! for more explains go 
[here](http://hackmysql.com/case4)

Comment: Okey, but when i remove GROUP_CONCAT and just use t.name i get same result no indexing.